# How to interchange or insert the characters between the arguments in Linux?

Tags: shell, mutt

We migrated apps from Solaris to Linux , and email functionality (mutt) behavior differs in Linux when attachment (-a) option is used. so instead of modifying all our shell scripts we are planning to write a wrapper script which will insert "--" in front of the 1st email occurrence.

`mutt -a "file1"  -a "file2" -s "subject" e1@email.com e2@mail.com < /dev/null`

to

`mutt -a "file1" -a "file2" -s "subject" "--" e1@email.com e2@mail.com < /dev/null`

Also, can we globally modify mutt functionality to ignore "--" for identifying the email?

Answer (score 0):

To insert `--`:

```
set -- -a "file1"  -a "file2" -s "subject" e1@email.com e2@mail.com

args=()
while getopts :a:s: opt; do 
    case $opt in 
        a) args+=( -a "$OPTARG" );; 
        s) args+=( -s "$OPTARG" );; 
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))
args=( "${args[@]}" -- "$@" )

echo "${args[@]}"
```

```
-a file1 -a file2 -s subject -- e1@email.com e2@mail.com
```

I don't understand what you mean with:

> globally modify mutt functionality to ignore "--" for identifying the email

The mutt man page explicitly provides for `--` to end options.